# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: arrays, char

I have a Uni project that requires us to create a Ceaear Cipher program and we have to do it in C. I have learnt Java but not C and as a result I have had to learn C in 4 weeks.

Anyway I'm trying to combine 2 char arrays together in the second for loop and then after that add the alphabet after the code word, when I try to do this it keeps giving me the error that I have posted this topic as "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". I can easily do this in Java but C is a little more complicated to me.

Is there just an easier way to do this or am I missing something all together. Any help is appreciated.

```
int main(){
  char mainAlphabet;
  char *mainPointer = &mainAlphabet;
  char codeWord[20];
  char codeAndAlphabet;
  int i=0;

    printf("Please enter a code word: ");
    scanf("%s", &codeWord);

  for(mainAlphabet=97 ; mainAlphabet<=122 ; mainAlphabet++){
    //printf("%c", mainAlphabet);
  }
  for(i=0 ; i < sizeof(codeWord); i++){
  codeAndAlphabet[i] = codeWord[i];
  }
  printf("%s \n", codeWord);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `codeAndAlphabet` is a `char`:

```
char codeAndAlphabet;
```

Note that it's just a *single* `char`, not an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`. So, now, the left-hand side of:

```
codeAndAlphabet[i] = codeWord[i]
```

is wrong because it's trying to use the subscripting (or indexing) syntax `[i]` with something that isn't subscriptable, which is exactly what your compiler error message said.